# An upper bound of pseudo-/VC-dimension

Tags: lg.learning, vc-dimension

Let $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \left\{f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}\right\}$ be a family of functions with bounded pseudo-dimension $\text{Pdim}(\mathcal{F})\le N$, i.e., the VC-dimension $\text{VCdim}(\left\{\text{sgn}(f(x)-r)|f\in\mathcal{F}\right\})\le N$. We can assume that functions in $\mathcal{F}$ satisfy some good properties, such as Lipschitzness and smoothness.

Let $\mathcal{F}^\prime$ be a linear combination of $f\in\mathcal{F}$ with different inputs, e.g., $\mathcal{F}^\prime=\left\{f^\prime|f^\prime(x_1,x_2)=f(x_1)-f(x_2),f\in\mathcal{F}\right\})$. Is it possible to obtain an upper bound of the pseudo-dimension $\text{Pdim}(\mathcal{F}^\prime)$ of such $\mathcal{F}^\prime$?

Edit (Aryeh): To clarify, the Pdim of a set of real-valued functions $\mathcal{F}$ acting on $\mathcal{X}$ is defined as the VCdim of the following set of $\{0,1\}$-valued functions acting on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\{
(x,t)\mapsto 1_{f(x)>t}; f\in\mathcal{F}
\}.
$$

Comment: The definition of Pdim needed some refinement; edited.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want $f(x_1)-f(x_2)$ and not $f_1(x_1)-f_2(x_2)$ ranging over $f_1,f_2\in\mathcal{F}$ ?

Comment: Yes. I am considering $f(x_1)-f(x_2)$, not $f_1(x_1)-f_2(x_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two real-valued function classes,
$\mathcal{F}_1$ acting on some set $\mathcal{X}_1$
and
$\mathcal{F}_2$ acting on some set $\mathcal{X}_2$.
I am going to bound the Pdim of
$\mathcal{F}_3$
acting on
$\mathcal{X}_1\times \mathcal{X}_2$
given by
$$
\mathcal{F}_3=\{
(x_1,x_2)\mapsto f_1(x_1)-f_2(x_2); 
f_1\in \mathcal{F}_1,
f_2\in \mathcal{F}_2
\}.
$$
Since obviously $\mathcal{F}_3\supseteq \mathcal{F}'$,
this also upper-bounds the Pdim of $\mathcal{F}'$.

By definition,
$$
\mathrm{Pdim}(\mathcal{F}_3)
=
\mathrm{VCdim}(\{
(x_1,x_2,t)\mapsto 1_{f_1(x_1)-f_2(x_2)>t}
;
f_1\in \mathcal{F}_1,
f_2\in \mathcal{F}_2
\}).
$$
Now we use the basic fact that
$$a+b>t \implies
\exists t_1,t_2: a>t_1, b>t_2
$$
to conclude
$$
\mathrm{Pdim}(\mathcal{F}_3)
\le
\mathrm{VCdim}(\{
(x_1,x_2,t_1,t_2)\mapsto 
1_{f_1(x_1)>t_1}\cdot 
1_{-f_2(x_2)>t_2}
;
f_1\in \mathcal{F}_1,
f_2\in \mathcal{F}_2
\}).
$$

The question has now been reduced to a more basic one:
If $\mathcal{H}_1, \mathcal{H}_2$
are Boolean function classes acting on
$\mathcal{X}_1, \mathcal{X}_2$, resp.,
how can we control the VCdim of
$\mathcal{H}_3$ acting on
$\mathcal{X}_1\times \mathcal{X}_2$
given by
$$
\mathcal{H}_3
=
\{
(x_1,x_2)\mapsto h_1(x_1)h_2(x_2);
h_1\in \mathcal{H}_1,
h_2\in \mathcal{H}_2
\}
$$
in terms of the VCdim of
$\mathcal{H}_1, \mathcal{H}_2$?

Clearly, on any sequence
$(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$,
the number of behaviors achieved by
$\mathcal{H}_3$—formally, the cardinality of the
projection/restriction of
$\mathcal{H}_3$
this set, denoted by
$\mathcal{H}_3[(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)]$—is upper-bounded by
$\mathcal{H}_1[x_1,\ldots,x_n]
\cdot
\mathcal{H}_2[y_1,\ldots,y_n]
$.
If $d_1,d_2$ are the VCdims of
$\mathcal{H}_1, \mathcal{H}_2$, resp,
then Sauer's lemma implies
$$
\mathcal{H}_3[(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)]
\le
\mathcal{H}_1[x_1,\ldots,x_n]
\cdot
\mathcal{H}_2[y_1,\ldots,y_n]
\le
\left(
\frac{e n}{d_1}
\right)^{d_1}
\cdot
\left(
\frac{e n}{d_2}
\right)^{d_2}
\le
\left(
\frac{2 e n}{d_1+d_2}
\right)^{d_1+d_2}
,
$$
where the last inequality is contained in the proof of
Lemma 16 in
https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v23/20-1353.html
It further follows from that lemma (taking $k=2$)
that
$$
\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H}_3)
\le
2\log(6)(d_1+d_2).
$$
The only remaining piece is the trivial observation that
$
\mathrm{Pdim}(\mathcal{F})=
\mathrm{Pdim}(-\mathcal{F})
$.

It follows that
$$
\mathrm{Pdim}(\mathcal{F}_3)
\le
2\log(6)(
\mathrm{Pdim}(\mathcal{F}_1)
+
\mathrm{Pdim}(\mathcal{F}_2)
).
$$

Comment: Sorry about the boldface in the middle. No idea how it got there or how to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! This is a very clear and concise result!

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. Just imagine that $f(x)>0$ for all $f$ and $x$. The differences $f(x_1)-f(x_2)$ can look arbitrarily horrendous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I was thinking about, but I can't construct a counterexample.

Comment: I don't think this is quite a counterexample. You are allowed a different threshold $t_i$ at each shattered point $x_i$. Thus, for example, the class of all increasing functions on $[0,1]$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ have infinite Pdim.

Comment: @Aryeh After your edit, the question starts to make sense. I still don't see why increasing functions would have infinite Pdim. From a set $\{a,b\}$ with $a<b$, how can you cut out only $a$?

Comment: It's essentially the VCdim of the collection of the induced epigraph sets. So step functions with many steps will have an epigraph with large VC-dim.